# how to add an object in json array with different name but same value

Tags: arrays, json

I am creating a chart right now I am facing an issue I have a json array with certain value, so below I have an element stock_change_p(can be positive or negative) what I want is to add a new element with same value (but positive) in the whole json array.

This is my array now

```
let data ={
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "sector_code": "0801",
            "stocks": [
                {                    
                       
                    "stock_change_p": "-1.34", 
                },
                {                  
                                    
                    "stock_change_p": "0.96",                  
                },
                {                 
                   
                    "stock_change_p": "-0.24",                
                }
            ]
        },
        
    ]
}
```

What I want my array to look later

```
let data ={
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "sector_code": "0801",
            "stocks": [
                {                    
                    "size": "1.34",     
                    "stock_change_p": "-1.34", 
                },
                {                  
                    "size": "0.96",                    
                    "stock_change_p": "0.96",                  
                },
                {                 
                    "size": "0.24",
                    "stock_change_p": "-0.24",                
                }
            ]
        },
        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to achieve the same result is provided below

```js
let data = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": [{
      "sector_code": "0801",
      "stocks": [{

          "stock_change_p": "-1.34",
        },
        {

          "stock_change_p": "0.96",
        },
        {

          "stock_change_p": "-0.24",
        }
      ]
    },

  ]
};

const addSize = (dataObj = data) => ({
  ...dataObj,
  data: [...dataObj.data.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    stocks: d.stocks.map(s => ({
      ...s,
      size: Math.abs(parseFloat(s.stock_change_p)).toString()
    }))
  }))]
});

console.log(addSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) negative values to positive

Try this code it's help you

```
 let data = {
      "status": "success",
      "data": [... ]
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

      let stocks = data.data[i].stocks;
      for (let j = 0; j < stocks.length; j++) {

        let obj = stocks[j];
        obj['size'] = Math.abs(obj.stock_change_p);
      }
    }
    console.log(data, 'data');
```

Comment: @music-cause, apologies, I think you have accepted my answer and not Mayur's answer.

Mayur, the values of the props 'stock_change_p' and 'size' are both shown to be 'string'.  Math.abs may not return 'string', I think. Apologies if I'm wrong.

Also, obj.size is sufficient and we do not require obj['size'] in this particular situation.